# Using sprites for a horizontal navigation

Tags: html, css, hover, sprite

I have the following code, and I am not sure why when I role over the first navA nothing seems to change but I am pretty sure it should, I am stumped.

**HTML**

```html
<div id="access" role="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li id="navA"><a href="http://localhost:8888/fiftyfity/?page_id=2"></a></li>
            <li id="navB"><a href="http://localhost:8888/fiftyfity/?page_id=9"></a></li>
            <li id="navC"><a href="http://localhost:8888/fiftyfity/?page_id=11"></a></li>
            <li id="navD"><a href="http://localhost:8888/fiftyfity/?page_id=13"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- #access -->
```

**CSS**

```css
#access {
    background-image: url("../images/mainNav.gif");
    width: 521px;
    height: 49px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#access li, #access a {
    height: 49px;
    display: block;
}

#access li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    text-indent: -9999em;
}

#navA { width: 98px; }
#navB { width: 131px; }
#navC { width: 123px; }
#navD { width: 138px; }

#navA a:hover { background-image: url("../images/mainNav.gif") 0px -49px no-repeat; }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with the declaration in the `#navA a:hover` selector. Try this:

```
#navA a:hover 
{ 
    background: url("../images/mainNav.gif") no-repeat 0px -49px; 
}
```

Comment: You should set the width to `#navA a` too, or else in some browsers ( almost all ) it will not have were to render your background for the link innerHTML is empty and therefor it has no width.

Comment: I got it to work by copying your code, I am not sure where the difference is though between mine and yours I just can't see it. Edit: Now I see, if I get rid of background-image and replace with background it works.